# How can I access files in Alfresco using the CMIS REST API?

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, cmis

I installed Alfresco Community v4.1 for use in my application. I want to access its contents (list files, add, delete etc.) using `CMIS REST API`. I don't find any example for the endpoint I need to use. I implemented a small `CMIS` client [(you can get information on it here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580963/cmisobjectnotfoundexception-when-trying-to-access-my-alfresco-repository/41601409?noredirect=1#comment70440770_41601409) using `Apache Chemistry` and listing the contents of my user's space and I obtain this result:

```
[Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/624914c7-3ca2-4937-a612-96f1df928cc1 - Dictionnaire de données
    [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/846c69d4-4ec2-44c8-972d-f975d9b98d41 - Modèles d'espace
        [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/09fe45df-9cba-4843-a1cb-944807e44267 - Projet de conception logicielle
....

[Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/ab5cab42-2b47-4042-a8f5-57bb06007cc3 - Espaces Utilisateurs
            [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/86f1c760-905e-4920-98a8-a6bdd10aa732 - ombinte
                [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/2dbc6156-fdfa-4ddc-9187-481992570369 - MonProjet
                    [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/fb3bb96f-3eb0-40a5-a890-3d06d6e781cf - Carnet 200
                    [Folder] workspace://SpacesStore/b9acaf70-d5d5-4dba-a354-bae63ba96072 - Carnet 100
                            [Docment] workspace://SpacesStore/9c3c6e63-e217-47a8-8216-298d2419cffa;1.0 - file.pdf
```

When I try to list the contents of a node I always get a `404` error.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/ab5cab42-2b47-4042-a8f5-57bb06007cc3
```

Where can I find documentation on how to implement CMIS REST API for Alfresco?

Comment: please read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764187/connection-with-alfresco-cmis/38764392#38764392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to access to your repository

try this worked fine for me

```
 private static Session getSession(String serverUrl, String username, String password) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(SessionParameter.USER, username);
    params.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, password);
    params.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, serverUrl);
    params.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
    List<Repository> repos = sessionFactory.getRepositories(params);
    if (repos.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Server has no repositories!");
    }
    return repos.get(0).createSession();
}
```

This method get the session from your repository with your own informations

```
serverUrl : http://" + ipAlfresco + "/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
username : admin 
password : admin
```

Hope that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The [official Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/cmis-and-alfresco.html) explains this pretty well. You shouldn't think of CMIS as a REST API itself. CMIS is an [interoperability standard](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=cmis#overview) that aims to provide a generic, vendor-agnostic means of querying your data.

Anyway... Your problem seems to be that the noderef you're using is for a folder, which the service you're hitting doesn't work for. Try that instead with...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/content/workspace/SpacesStore/9c3c6e63-e217-47a8-8216-298d2419cffa
```

...and see if you find your content.

For folders, try a [WebDAV](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4783-client-webdav) link, e.g.: http://localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav/Sites/swsdp/documentLibrary/Agency%20Files