# How to upload a document using CMIS?

Tags: cmis, opencmis

I am learning CMIS and have come across code similar to following which creates a document using CMIS. I want to use createDocument method of CMIS to upload a file stored in a folder in my local machine. How can I achieve that?

```
Folder parent = ....

String name = "myNewDocument.txt";

// properties 
// (minimal set: name and object type id)
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);

// content
byte[] content = "Hello World!".getBytes();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);

// create a major version
Document newDoc = parent.createDocument(properties, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `FileInputStream` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a convenience method to create a `ContentStream` object from a file.

See: https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/util/ContentStreamUtils.html#createFileContentStream-java.io.File-

See also:
https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/content/index.html#content-streams

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this method and it's worked for me

```
public static void upload(String serverUrl, String username, String password, String cheminFichierSource, String nomDestination, String cheminFichierDestination, String extentionFichier) {
 try {    
   Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);
   Folder root = getFolderByPath(serverUrl, username, password, cheminFichierDestination);

   Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_DOCUMENT.value());
   String name = nomDestination + "." + extentionFichier;

   System.out.println("name:" + name);
   properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
   List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
   List<Ace> removeAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
   List<Policy> policies = new LinkedList<Policy>();
   File file = new File(cheminFichierSource);
   ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl("content." + extentionFichier, BigInteger.valueOf(file.length()),
new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file), new FileInputStream(file));
   Document dc = root.createDocument(properties, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR, policies, addAces, removeAces, session.getDefaultContext());
//idnewdoc=dc.getId();

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "ERREUR Consultation! ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
     }
    }
```

You can also read more in [How to get connected with Alfresco repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764187/connection-with-alfresco-cmis/38764392#38764392) (simplly the get session method).

Also don't forget that in this method every thing is static (the file name the path ...).

Hope that helped you.